# Trouble with assigning (or re-overloading) the assignment operator in Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble assigning the assignment operator.

I have successfully overloaded `__setattr__`.  But after the object is initialized, I want `__setattr__` to do something else, so I try assigning it to be another function, `__setattr2__`.

Code:

```
class C(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.__setattr__ = self.__setattr2__

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print "first, setting", name
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

    def __setattr2__(self, name, value):
        print "second, setting", name
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

c = C()
c.x = 1
```

What I get:

```
first, setting x
first, setting __setattr__
first, setting x
```

What I want/expect:

```
first, setting x
first, setting __setattr__
second, setting x
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup):

> ### Special method lookup for new-style classes
>
> For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are
> only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not
> in the object’s instance dictionary. That behaviour is the reason why
> the following code raises an exception (unlike the equivalent example
> with old-style classes):
>
> ```
> >>> class C(object):
> ...     pass
> ...
> >>> c = C()
> >>> c.__len__ = lambda: 5
> >>> len(c)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: object of type 'C' has no len()
> ```

Comment: +1. I knew the behaviour existed but couldn't find the relevant reference in the docs.

Comment: Great answer as to why I can't do it.  The only thing I don't understand is that first I tried it with old-style classes (assigning by `self.__dict__[name] = value`), and it also didn't work.

Comment: @chappy: old-style as in `class C:` rather than `class C(object):`?

Comment: Yes, that too.  (in addition to using `__dict__` for assignment)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a flag to indicate that `__init__` is still in progress?

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Use the superclass's __setattr__ because we've overridden our own.
        super(C, self).__setattr__('initialising', True)
        self.x = 0
        # the very last thing we do in __init__ is indicate that it's finished
        super(C, self).__setattr__('initialising', False)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if self.initialising:
            print "during __init__, setting", name
            # I happen to like super() rather than explicitly naming the superclass
            super(C, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            print "after __init__, setting", name
            super(C, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```

Comment: Really nice workaround, thank you.  The fact that I have to use a workaround, though, makes me suspect that I should solve my more general problem a different way.  But in the mean time I'll use this!

Comment: @chappy: I totally agree with "I should solve my more general problem a different way". I always feel squeamish rummaging around in `__dict__`. In my opinion, whenever one feels the need for `__setattr__`, one can generally get the job done with finer-grained [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) or [properties](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) (or just a general change of strategy). Your original idea looks like a workaround too!